# Extjs: Setting an object's data to be shown in a form

Tags: date, object, extjs, binding, load

I currently have an object with various fields (mostly date fields) as shown from the console log below. There are more fields than this but all are similar. Also I am aware that they are all 1970 this is how we set them on the .net side.

> Object {
>   gasSafeLicenseNo: "3132571",
>   ngDomesticPipework: "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
>   lpgDomesticPipework: "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
>   lpgCentralHeating: "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
>   lpgDomesticBoats: "1970-01-01T00:00:00"
>   lpgDomesticCaravans: "1970-01-01T00:00:00"

I have a  view with a form in holding all the date fields etc etc..

> ```
>                    {
>                         xtype: 'datefield',
>                         labelWidth: 50,
>                         name: 'ngDomesticPipework',
>                         fieldLabel: 'NG'
>                     },
> ```

All fields have identical names in the model, view and data object but will not load into my form ready for editing. I am simply getting the form element with a component query setting the data to be the object I want to load and calling load record.

> ```
>            var data = record.get('engineer').gasSafeCard;
>            gasSafeFormCmp.loadRecord(data);
> ```

Thanks folks massive help as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data object is not a model instance, use [`setValues`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues) instead or `loadRecord`.

```
gasSafeFormCmp.getForm().loadRecord(data);
```

Comment: Hi Rixo thanks but there still not loading into the view ive tried both methods, could it be anything else?

Comment: Yes, since your dates are strings you should configure the date format in your fields, probably using [`altFormats`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-altFormats) to save `dateFormat` for desired display format. FYI, your date format is `'Y-m-d\\TH:i:s'`.

Comment: Genius, I hope your getting paid enough to help people like me! Thanks again.